# How to access member of a static class which is inside another static class

Tags: c#, class, static

I have following class structure

```
public class MainClass
{
    private static class Class1
    {
         private static class Class2
         {
             public const int Id = 2;
         }
    }

    public void getId()
    {
        // I want to access Id here
    }
}
```

Now I want to access the variable Id which is inside Class2

I tried like `Class1.Class2.Id;` But it is not working
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to access this from outside of the `Class1` you need to change the access modifier from `private` to `public` (accessible from anywhere) or `internal` (accessible from the assembly).

```
public class MainClass
{
    private static class Class1
    {
         // note the modifier change for Class2
         public static class Class2
         {
             public const int Id = 2;
         }
    }

    public void getId()
    {
        var id = Class1.Class2.Id;
    }
}
```